# Two way teleportation with maintained speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a 2D kinematic spaceship which is being moved by `rigidbody.MovePosition` in its `FixedUpdate()`. The ship has four rays coming out of it in four directions. Each ray checks for a bool if it hits a force field. Depending on the bool status (which can be changed on MouseDown), the ship is either moved away or towards the field.

I also have a working two way teleportation system, where if the ship collides with one teleport it appears in the other, and vice versa.

The effect that I am looking for is the ship to continue moving in the same direction with the same speed (with which it entered the first teleport), after it comes out of the second. I was sort of able to mimic this effect by adding a vector to the ship's `transform` as it exits the teleport, but the movement is very fast and sudden (code commented out below).

Here's the script attached to both teleports -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class teleport : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform exitTeleport;
    static Transform thisTeleport;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("ship"))
        {
            if (thisTeleport == exitTeleport)
            return;
            thisTeleport = this.transform;
            col.transform.position = exitTeleport.transform.position;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("ship"))
        {
            if (exitTeleport == thisTeleport)
            {
                thisTeleport = null;
            }
            //col.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing and reapplying the `Rigidbody2D.velocity` of the ship as it enters and exits the teleporter in order to maintain the momentum.

```
public Transform exitTeleport;
static Transform thisTeleport;
private Vector3 shipvelocity;

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("ship"))
    {
        if (thisTeleport == exitTeleport)
            return;
        thisTeleport = this.transform;
        shipvelocity = col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
        col.transform.position = exitTeleport.transform.position;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("ship"))
    {
        if (exitTeleport == thisTeleport)
        {
            thisTeleport = null;
        }
        col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = shipvelocity;
        //col.transform.position += new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Ship teleports, but does not move. Also, Debug.Log(shipvelocity) in Update() shows (0.0, 0.0) all the time, even when its moving. Wonder why. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Looks like I had Rigidbody instead of Rigidbody2D. I also moved the statement retrieving the velocity up one line. Try those changes out and let me know.

Comment: Apparently, rb.velocity/rb2d.velocity does not work with MovePosition, hence the (0, 0) velocity, and also maybe why this is still not working. [Link here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/moveposition-velocity.425450/). The guy posted his solution but I am not sure how to use that in my script.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522344/back-and-forth-movement-using-rigidbody2d-moveposition) is the script attached to the ship, with MovePosition being called in fixedUpdate(). If I am somehow able to get the ship's velocity, I am sure your solution will work.

Comment: Velocity can be found by finding distance traveled over time. Store the position a couple frames before it reaches the teleporter, and then find the position once it reaches the teleporter, and figure out how much time has passed between the two points:
`(curpos-prevpos)/deltatime`
I am not positive that setting velocity while the body is kinematic is possible or recommended, but it is worth a shot before deciding to use an alternative to MovePosition.

Comment: Right now, I have - `rb.MovePosition(newPos);
  shipSpeed = newPos - oldPos/Time.deltaTime;
  ` in the ship script's fixedUpdate. The Vector2 shipSpeed has been declared at the very beginning of script. Debug log shows a constantly changing shipSpeed which increases/decreases by 5, the vector value I have set to add/substract to the ship's position. On the teleport's OnTriggerExit2D I have - `Vector2 shipSpeed = col.GetComponent<shipScript>().shipSpeed; col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += shipSpeed;` This is still not working, ship is still stuck on exit.

Comment: If I do not divide shipSpeed by deltaTime, I get a constant Vector2 of (0.1, 0) or (-0.1, 0) etc, depending on the direction of the ship's movement. `Debug.Log (shipSpeed)` in the teleport's OnTriggerExit2D shows only one instance in the console. Maybe, I need a way to keep adding shipSpeed to the ship's position on teleport exit.

Comment: First off, make sure you are dividing (newPos - oldPos) by time, not just oldPos.
What happens if you directly set the velocity after exit to an arbitrary value (like 5)?  
`col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(5,0);`
Does the ship move in the +x as expected?

Comment: `(newPos - oldPos)` shows (+/- 5, 0) now. You were right, I was missing the parentheses. Tried setting the velocity to Vector2 (5, 0), but ship still does not move. `Debug.Log(col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity)` does show (5, 0) though. Tried changing ship to Dynamic Rigidbody, no change in behavior. Is `col.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = exitTeleport.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;` not letting the ship leave?